# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected left_input to have shape (134,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to build the Manhattan LSTM model. But I have a problem with the output shape when i calculate the manhattan distance.

Concats information:

```
Tensor("concatenate_26/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 100), dtype=float32)
```

Lambda info:

```
Tensor("lambda_25/Exp:0", shape=(?, 1, 100), dtype=float32)
```

I've tried to change output_shape in Lambda and change input parameters of manhattan function. But it didn't work.

```py
def exponent_neg_manhattan_distance(x, hidden_size=100):
    return K.exp(-K.sum(K.abs(x[:,:hidden_size] - x[:,hidden_size:]), axis=1, keepdims=True))

left_input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype='int32', name='left_input')
right_input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype='int32', name='right_input')

input_left = embed_layer(left_input)
input_right = embed_layer(right_input)
# print(input_left.shape)
# print(input_right.shape)
shared_lstm = LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, activation='softmax')

left_output = shared_lstm(input_left)
right_output = shared_lstm(input_right)

concats = concatenate([left_output, right_output], axis=-1)
malstm_output = Lambda(exponent_neg_manhattan_distance, output_shape=(134, ))(concats)
```

I expect the shape of Lambda to be `(?,134,100)`

Comment: The problem is not about the output of the lambda, the error is about the input layer called left_input, it is expecting a shape of (None, 134), but the input data has shape (None, 1).

Comment: [Matias Valdenegro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/matias-valdenegro)